# New FireFox BorderRadius/Rotate Animation Bug?

Tags: jquery, firefox, rotation, css

I've recently upgraded to Firefox 14.0.1 during a plugin build. The plugin animates border-radius, border-width, border-color along with various other properties simultaneously. There aren't any problems with other browsers, or the previous version of FireFox, but after the update I'm noticing severe fragmenting/artifacting during border radius animation when animated with rotate. Below is the code I have for rotate:

```
/* ROTATE */
function animate_rotate(degree,Speed,AnimateDegree){
   /* FACTOR DEGREE */if(degree<AnimateDegree){
        ++degree; Screens.current_rotate=degree;
  }else if(degree>AnimateDegree){
        --degree; Screens.current_rotate=degree;
  };
  /* APPLY THE NEW ROTATION ANGLE TO IE>9 */
  if(!ievers<=8){
       $ScreensLightbox.css({'-moz-transform':'translateX(0) rotate('+degree+'deg)','-moz-transform-origin':''+Screens.LBRotateHandle[0]+'% '+Screens.LBRotateHandle[1]+'%','-webkit-transform':'translateX(0) rotate('+degree+'deg)','-webkit-transform-origin':''+Screens.LBRotateHandle[0]+'% '+Screens.LBRotateHandle[1]+'%',/* Opera */'-o-transform':'translateX(0) rotate('+degree+'deg)','-o-transform-origin':''+Screens.LBRotateHandle[0]+'% '+Screens.LBRotateHandle[1]+'%',/* IE>=9 */'-ms-transform':'rotate('+degree+'deg)','-ms-transform-origin':''+Screens.LBRotateHandle[0]+'% '+Screens.LBRotateHandle[1]+'%'});
   };
/* PUSH INSTANCE TIMER-ON ARRAY */
Screens.Rotate_Timer.push(setTimeout(function({animate_rotate(degree,Speed,AnimateDegree)},Speed/63));
};
```

and here's the function for animating the border radius:

```
/* BORDER RADIUS */
function animate_border_radius(SetBorderRadius,AnimateBorderRadius,Speed,Effect){
     $ScreensLightbox.css({'border-top-left-radius':SetBorderRadius,'border-top-right-radius':SetBorderRadius,'border-bottom-left-radius':SetBorderRadius,'border-bottom-right-radius':SetBorderRadius})
    .animate({borderTopLeftRadius:AnimateBorderRadius, borderTopRightRadius:AnimateBorderRadius,borderBottomLeftRadius:AnimateBorderRadius,borderBottomRightRadius:AnimateBorderRadius,WebkitBorderTopLeftRadius:AnimateBorderRadius,WebkitBorderTopRightRadius:AnimateBorderRadius,WebkitBorderBottomLeftRadius:AnimateBorderRadius,WebkitBorderBottomRightRadius:AnimateBorderRadius,MozBorderRadius:AnimateBorderRadius},
    {duration:Speed,queue:false,specialEasing:{borderTopLeftRadius:Effect,borderTopRightRadius:Effect,borderBottomLeftRadius:Effect,borderBottomRightRadius:Effect,WebkitBorderTopLeftRadius:Effect,WebkitBorderTopRightRadius:Effect,WebkitBorderBottomLeftRadius:Effect,WebkitBorderBottomRightRadius:Effect,MozBorderRadius:Effect}});
    };
```

anyone having similar issues when trying to animate Rotate and Border Radius at the same time in the latest Firefox? Thanks!

Comment: are you sure that only firefox has this issue?

Comment: Only the latest version of Firefox, the previous versions worked perfectly, and IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera all work perfectly.

Comment: Forgot to mention, that it will work just fine when animating either the border radius or rotate by themselves. As soon as you animate both of them at the same time it fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're seeing a very similar issue. We have some images that fade into view with the animate function.  Works great in all browsers including FF until the 14.0.1 release.

```
// image animation
$("#imgDisplay img").each(function(index) {
    var tm = 800 * index;
    var imgTop = $(this).css('margin-top');
    arr = imgTop.split('px');
    var imgTopStart = (arr[0]*1)-50;
    $(this).css({
        "opacity": "0",
        "margin-top": imgTopStart+"px"
    }).show();

    $(this).delay(tm).animate({
        opacity: 1,
        "margin-top": imgTop
    }, 1500, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar bug and adding translateZ helped. I can't tell for sure that this will help in your case, but worth trying:

```
-moz-transform: rotate(10deg) translateZ(1px);
```